# Which token should I use in my React app call backend API , which forward call to Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, swagger, msal-react

In my React app I use OAuth 2.0 auth code grant for authentication , and use Graph APi to make most of the requests (I have an app registered in Azure AD). They work perfectly with the access token I received using MSAL2 Provider (toolkit).

```
Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
  clientId: config.clientId,
  authority: config.authority,
  redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
  scopes: [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "Place.ReadWrite",
    "Place.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read",
    "People.Read",
  ],
});
```

I get the access token with following function:

```
const getAccessToken = async () => {
  let token;
  if (Providers.globalProvider.state === ProviderState.SignedIn) {
    token = await Providers.globalProvider.getAccessToken();
    token = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return token;
};
```

Recently I got another service to do but not directly to the Graph API but by our Backend who after some validation make a query to Graph API ( exactly its a room update call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/${roomId}
```

My service :

```
const updateRoom=async (roomId:string|undefined, room:Room):Promise<void>=> {
  return axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/rooms/${roomId}`,     {capacity:Number(room.capacity),equipments:room.tags},{
  headers: {
    Authorization: await getAccessToken(),
  },
  })
```

But what I get from the server is status 500, AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n.

When testing our backend app in Swagger- > it works , the room is updated correctly. I have tried to copy the token from the Swagger and use the same in my React app--> also works , but I can not use for this purpose the access token I receive from MSAL2. Why does it happen? Where to find a solution either on the front or backend?

Comment: how you composed your backend API? asp.net core web api? and how your web api call  the ms room update graph api? you mentioned that `after some validation make a query to Graph API`, so what's the validation here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same account to test request in Swagger and React app? As docs say only "work or school account" is supported for Place update. can it be an issue?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your function use patch method?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a backend api which required to be called by your react client app. Then your backend api also required to call ms graph api to update the room. So I deduce [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview) matched your scenario.

Then I have a question here, how your backend web app to call the ms graph api? There are 2 possibilities, one is that it calls ms graph api on behalf the application-self, which should use client credential flow. Another one is that it calls ms graph api on behalf of the signed-in user which required to use [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

When using client credential flow, it's not necessary to set microsoft authentication for your backend app, it depends on yourself to add authentication or not. And if you called [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), then it doesn't support application type of api permissin, then you are impossible to use client credential flow here.

Let's focus on the first scenario. The whole progress should look like this: your react client app generate an access token and use it to call your backend api --> your backend api validate the token and try to call graph api on behalf of the signed in user. In this scenario, you should protect your backend api with Azure AD first, so that it can managed by Azure AD authorization. Then using On-behalf-flow allows you to generate another access token with the access token send from react client app and use it to call ms graph api.

I have a sample with asp.net core MVC(represent the client app) and and asp.net core web api. In my MVC project, I generate an access token for calling the api.

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<string> GetAsync() {
            var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://aad_client_id_exposing_api/Tiny.Read" });

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://localhost:7212/WeatherForecast")
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
                }
            };

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            var res = "";
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
               res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return "hello" + res;
        }
```

Pls note the scope I used above, it's not for graph api, but an api permission which exposed by ourself, [more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration) can be seen here.

Then this is my web api. In program.cs and appsettings.json, I have the following to protect my api with Azure AD, with the nuget package `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph`:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); 

 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "aad_client_app_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "Domain": "tenant_name",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id" // A guid (Tenant ID = Directory ID) or 'common' or 'organizations' or 'consumers'
    //"Audience": "api://aad_app_client_id_which_exposed_api" //I used the same aad client app to expose api and consent api permission, so I can comment this line
  },
  "Graph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

And this is my web api controller:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public WeatherForecastController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [RequiredScope("Tiny.Read")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> GetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var name = user.DisplayName;
            return name;
            //return "world";
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked for me. I'm afraid your issue happened for the scope you used in the client app, it should be the scope you exposed by yourself but not the one which is used for calling graph api.

[image]