# AAD Access token per API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-identity

**Current Behavior -**

From our service-A, we are calling service-B. We are currently using `client_credentials` as a way to generate access_token for service-B(as shown below).

[image]

Service-B is validating token generated at their end and everything is working fine.

**Expected behavior** -

So, now we are looking `per API based whitelisting`. So, in above case service-A will be able to call all API of service-B and we want to stop that. So, looking for help to expand our current implementation to support same without changing resource (As resource means service-2 in our team).

Thus, **expected behavior will be service-A can call API-1 of service-B, but not API-2**.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you are using Oauth 1.0 which you need to set `resource` and this makes you can't set API scope inside the authorization, you need to use OAuth 2.0. By the way, client credential flow will make the scope set to `xxx/.default`, this flow won't contain scope name as well, so you can't use client credential flow as well.

I have a sample here. Firstly, here's the settings in Service-B. I integrated Azure AD into my web api project.

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "client_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id"
  },
```

Then in my web api:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{

    public WeatherForecastController(){}

    [RequiredScope("Tiny.Read1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        return "world";
    }

    [HttpGet("greet")]
    [RequiredScope("Tiny.Read")]
    public string greet() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I used auth code flow to generate an access token which containing the scope I defined:

[image]

Then here's my test result:

[image]

About how to expose custom API scope, you can follow this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#expose-delegated-permissions-scopes). This answer showed how to [generate access token by auth code flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172223/14574199). But if you are trying to generate access token in Service-A to call Service-B, you may use on_behalf_flow, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015088/14574199) contained code snippet with Microsoft identity and use _tokenAcquisition to generate access token, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799358/14574199) is for a client call AAD protected API.

Comment: If you insist on using client credential flow, then you can only try to authorize the `roles` claim instead of `scp` claim. Then you can have a look at [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#expose-application-permissions-app-roles) to expose roles instead of API scope.  And you have to use `[Authorize(Roles = "roles")]` instead of `RequiredScope`.

Comment: You can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore) for adjusting code in Service_B.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: In an Azure AD Application, App roles can be defined which represents a service, app or API.

I created two Azure AD Applications **`ServiceA`** and **`ServiceB`**.

In **`ServiceB`** application, I created sample App roles like below:

[image]

In **`ServiceA`** application, I added required permissions like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
resource:api://ServiceBClientID
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token in the roles claim only the **`api.read`** and **`api2.read`** is present not **`api3.read`**.

[image]

This is the possible workaround which can be implemented to achieve your scenario. The App roles can be assigned to Users, groups or Service Principals.

**Reference:**

[Add app roles and get them from a token - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)