# Issues with Access token Authentication using MSAL with Angular and c# webapi

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, msal

i need to authorize a Angular user to access my protected WebAPI.
I am in c# back end where i need to authorize a login using MSAL (front end in angular creates the session and gets me the access token ). I need to verify the token in C# web api to determine if the token is valid. I will get the user's email and access token from the Angular front end.

I searched to silently check for authentication using following code but i cannot find how to create a Account

```
 var result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, userAccount)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

creating account takes following parameters but It is not returning any result.

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
    var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

Before that the code looks like below

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID")
        .WithRedirectUri("redirect URL")
        .Build();
```

Comment: MSAL doesn't validate access tokens from client applications. You need to configure JWT authentication for that. Sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/README-incremental-instructions.md

Answer (score 0):

> i need to authorize a Angular user to access my protected WebAPI.

This means you need to integrate AAD into your Angular application and you also need to use AAD to protect your web API. This will make your Angular to provide sign-in feature and generate access token to visit the API, and your API should validate the token via AAD and decide if the request could access the API or return 401.

I don't know angular so I can just share an sample here.

First, just like what @juunas said, you need to configure JWT authentication. You can also take a look at [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview). It requires to expose an API in AAD, and it's necessary to have code below in your API application. With code below, your API with `[Authorize]` attribute would return 401 response if the request didn't have a correct access token.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "allowall",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

[image]

Then the next, for Angular application, following the sample in [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code#get-the-completed-code-sample) we will get an application which allows us to sign in and calling ms graph api.

if we changed the configuration `protectedResourceMap` in `app.module.ts` from
`protectedResourceMap.set(GRAPH_ENDPOINT, ['user.read']);` to `protectedResourceMap.set("https://localhost:7072/WeatherForecast", ['api://client-id/custom_api_permission_name']);`, and change the `this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT)` to `this.http.get("https://localhost:7072/WeatherForecast")` in `profile.component.ts`, we will change the request to call our protected web api with the authenticated credential.

[image]

Comment: I did as mentioned above. In my authorized. I am trying to get authenticated by C#  it is throwing following exception >

AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests

Comment: Also i added the [Authorized] attribute to the controller now all methods are returning a 401

Comment: adding `[Authorized]` should make requests get 401 error. Do you know whether the issue happened in api project or your angular project? If it's in angular app, pls take a look at the sample I shared above, or [tthis sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api) and see if you are lacking of something. Because I don't know Angular coding, so I can only say we need to use msal in angualr to get user authenticated and authorized, when we do the authorization, we need to use the api permission. Finding the permission pls.

Comment: if we want to test if the api is correct, we need to manually generate an access token using the auth code flow. You might take a look at [the first 2 steps in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172223/14574199) to generate an access token and use it to test the api and see if it worked.

Comment: I am facing the following issue now on authentication. 

Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests

Comment: could you pls let me know when and where the issue happened? When you trying to sign in your angular app? Or you are trying to generate an access token via postman? I also found this similar issue which mentioned `When using a SPA, Azure Identiy requires that the token redemption comes from a browser (not a web server). The request for the code exchange must contain the 'Origin' header. If not, you get the error: "Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error